# How to make a list from several nested lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.6, python-2.x

I have  a following nested list (All are in one list: One master list (Master) contains two list both  of them contain by one list)

```
Master = \
["E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin [u'BGD_4_new_district', u'BGD_3_old_district', u'BGD_2_division', u'BGD_1_all', u'BGD_5_Upazilla', u'BGD_4_old_district', u'BGD_6_Union_court', u'BGD_6_Union', u'BD_exposed_coastal_area', u'BD_drought', u'BGD_1_River', u'BGD_1_River_detail', u'BD_international_bnd', u'BGD_1_River_1', u'BGD_7_Mauza', u'test', u'BGD_5_UpazillaAnno', u'BGD_4_new_districtAnno', u'BGD_4_new_districtAnno2']", 
 "E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BCAS_BD_Infrastructure    [u'BD_Health_Infrastructures_1', u'BD_Railway_Establishments_1', u'BGD_roads_1']"]
```

Now I want to make a list (as windows path) whose one element as below:(for the first list)

```
"E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\u'BGD_4_new_district"
```

again the included `'u'` character for unicode  and `"'"` after it  also be removed so finally it be:
In a  elements in a List named "My_Path" are

```
"E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_4_new_district" 
"E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_3_old_district"
..........
..........
"E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BCAS_BD_Infrastructur\\BD_Health_Infrastructures_1"
```

@ Martijn Pieters
My arcpy code is

```
import arcpy,os
p=[]
D=[]
admin="E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace =admin
datasetList = arcpy.ListDatasets("*", "Feature")
for dataset in datasetList:
d=str(dataset)
D.append(d)
dList = arcpy.ListTables() + arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() + arcpy.ListRasters()
for dataset in arcpy.ListDatasets():
    arcpy.env.workspace=os.path.join(admin,dataset)
    dList+=arcpy.ListDatasets()+arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    p.append(str(arcpy.env.workspace)+str(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()))##--this makes list
```

Comment: You have one list with two strings. They are not nested lists. Part of the elements *look* like lists, but they are still just strings. You called `str()` on existing lists with unicode values.

Comment: Show us the code that build this list in the first place? I can help you fix these strings, but it'd be much, much easier and better if you didn't build these values in the first place.

Comment: @  Martijn Pieters i m usin arcpy library

Comment: arcpy does not produce output like this unless you call `str()` on something (or use string formatting). What is the code that produces `Master`?

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters yes boss i used str() formatting

Comment: Then please show that bit of code and I can help you avoid the EOF you are seeing with my attempt to repair the damage. Edit your question, add the lines of code that create the `Master` list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two strings with python lists *embedded* in them. They are not actual lists.

You can go back to making these into lists with unicode values with the `ast.literal_eval()` function. That feels like we are fixing a problem that was caused by other code, the better fix would be to not build these values like these in the first place.

```
from ast import literal_eval
import os.path

output = []
for entry in Master:
    base, lst = entry.split(None, 1)
    for name in literal_eval(lst):
        output.append(os.path.join(base, name))
```

This produces proper unicode paths (a good idea on Windows):

```
>>> output
[u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_4_new_district', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_3_old_district', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_2_division', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_1_all', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_5_Upazilla', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_4_old_district', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_6_Union_court', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_6_Union', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BD_exposed_coastal_area', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BD_drought', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_1_River', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_1_River_detail', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BD_international_bnd', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_1_River_1', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_7_Mauza', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\test', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_5_UpazillaAnno', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_4_new_districtAnno', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_4_new_districtAnno2', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BCAS_BD_Infrastructure\\BD_Health_Infrastructures_1', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BCAS_BD_Infrastructure\\BD_Railway_Establishments_1', u'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BCAS_BD_Infrastructure\\BGD_roads_1']
>>> print output[0]
E:\GIS_DOCUMENT\BCAS_Map\BCAS_All.gdb\BD_Admin\BGD_4_new_district
```

If you can, you want to change the original code to produce a *dictionary* instead, one that uses the base as keys, and a list of names as the value:

```
{'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BCAS_BD_Infrastructure': [u'BD_Health_Infrastructures_1',
                                                                      u'BD_Railway_Establishments_1',
                                                                      u'BGD_roads_1'],
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin': [u'BGD_4_new_district',
                                                        u'BGD_3_old_district',
                                                        u'BGD_2_division',
                                                        u'BGD_1_all',
                                                        u'BGD_5_Upazilla',
                                                        u'BGD_4_old_district',
                                                        u'BGD_6_Union_court',
                                                        u'BGD_6_Union',
                                                        u'BD_exposed_coastal_area',
                                                        u'BD_drought',
                                                        u'BGD_1_River',
                                                        u'BGD_1_River_detail',
                                                        u'BD_international_bnd',
                                                        u'BGD_1_River_1',
                                                        u'BGD_7_Mauza',
                                                        u'test',
                                                        u'BGD_5_UpazillaAnno',
                                                        u'BGD_4_new_districtAnno',
                                                        u'BGD_4_new_districtAnno2']}
```

Comment: what the heck! i m not able to use it; it comes with error of EOF

Comment: @SharifulIslam: Then your actual data contains more than what `literal_eval()` can handle.